# Testing WorkManagers

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, workmanagers

I am having trouble to test a CommonJ workManager. I have no idea which approach I should follow. I created a worker class which implements the task to be executed and a WorkListener which updates the status of the job (e.g. started, completed, rejected and so on). 
By using unit tests I can test the Worker and Listener object in isolation, but that's not enough in my point of view. I would like to  test the cooperation between these two objects.

For example, a possibility would be to create a  Worker object  and mock out the Listener :

```
expect(mockWorkListener.JobStarted());
expect(mockWorkListener.JobCompleted());
workManger.schedule(new Worker(Services...), mockWorkListener);
```

Comment: so you want to unit test the connection between the `workManager` and the `Worker` classes it invokes?